# DB2-clob data to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, db2, postgresql-9.2

We are planning to move data in DB2(28) to PostgreSQL(9.2).

We have already created database schema and tables in PostgreSQL. I am able to do data export from DB2 to csv format.

For importing data in PostgreSQL, the docs say "Copy command" which copies data from a file to the table.

In DB2, if data is of CLOB type, then separate file is created where CLOB data is kept. The main (data.csv) file contains references to CLOBs. How to import CLOB data in such cases?
I searched on net but could not find any opensource tool from PostgreSQL.

Comment: I work with this tool: http://www.sql-workbench.net and it can import BLOB from CSV files like that: http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/command-import.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a ready-to-use solution but may be a starting point. As far as I remember, DB2 is offering a ODBC interface. On the other hand on PostgreSQL you are able to "import" ODBC databases via Foreign data wrapper.The first step can be found at [documentation](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrappers#odbc_fdw). May be worth a try.